# Fineuploader Validate Event

Tags: validation, fine-uploader

We have just purchased a licence for fineuploader and it works great.
However, the documentation, after basic setup is rather confusing.
We are trying to handle the validate event but cant find any information about what the event data is such as valid extension etc and how we can inform users about any errors happening in the validation phase.

Would appreciate any assistance

Answer (score 1):

The validate event is documented in quite a bit of detail in the [events documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html) at http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/events.html#validate.

As the [validation documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/validation.html) says, you can use the validate event to enforce your own custom rules.  You are given the name and size of the file in your callback handler.  If you need access to more information (such as the actual file), you can declare a [`submit` event callback handler](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#submit) instead.  When `submit` is called, an ID is available for the file, and you can address it using any of the other [API methods](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html) that require a file ID.

If you only need to validate based on file extension, use the built in validation for that.  See the [`validation` config options](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#validation) for more details.

You can display a message to the user however you see fit.  The [`onError` callback](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#error) will be invoked on a validation error.  If you are using Fine Uploader UI, the [`showMessage` function](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-ui.html#showMessage) will also be invoked with the error message.

Please have a close look at the portions of the documentation linked to above, as well as the [live demo that includes validation on the home page](http://fineuploader.com/demos#various-options).

Comment: Many thanks for your reply.We have already looked at the documentation but we cant figure out how to for example show an alert box if a file is selected which is not part of the allowed extensions. Is it possible for you to give us an idea of where and how and to what we need to hookuo to to get the necessary information to achieve such a simple task. Thank you.

Comment: An alert will be displayed automatically by Fine Uploader UI, by default, if you specify a list of valid extensions via the proper `validation` option and a file is encountered with an invalid extension.

Comment: We are using the basic configuration. On the custom build the only option selected was the validation (jQuery version) and on the options the uploaderType is set to 'basic'. No errors show when an invalid file is selected. Thanks.

Comment: Then display an alert using whichever method you prefer.  Fine Uploader is not involved there since you have elected to build your own custom UI.  As mentioned in my answer, validation errors will be passed to an `onError` callback handler.

Comment: we have this event registered:
.on('error', function (event, id, name, errorReason, xhrOrXdr) {
            bootbox.alert(qq.format("Error on file number {} - {}.  Reason: {}", id, name, errorReason))
NOTHING SHOWS!

Comment: The error callback is invoked for validation failures, so there is most likely an issue with your code.  You'll need to look into the dev console for details.  Without only a very small fragment of your code, it's hard to see where your issue is.